# MYSQL query for getting no of record with multiple category

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, where-clause, having

So I have 1 table jobcatlist with 2 columns certification_id and JobCategory_id
1 certification_id can have multiple Jobcategories
like **(Preschool 1, Primary 2, Intermediate 3, Middle 4)**

I prepared the 1st query for getting the total no of certifications with multiple categories
this query

```
SELECT certification_id, COUNT(certification_id) AS cert_count
FROM jobcatlist 
GROUP BY certification_id
HAVING COUNT(certification_id) > 1
```

and it looks correct to me, please let me know if it's not

**so I got stuck with my second problem where I want to get the no of certifications with multiple category where specific Category is there like Preschool 1**

I am trying this query but its not correct

```
SELECT certification_id, COUNT(certification_id) AS cert_count
FROM jobcatlist 
WHERE jobcategory_id = 1
GROUP BY certification_id
HAVING  COUNT(certification_id) > 1 
ORDER BY certification_id DESC
```

Comment: Hi Rik, can you share sample input tables, current output and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE jobcategory_id = 1
```

filters out all other `jobcategory_id`s, so, assuming that the combination of `certification_id` and `jobcategory_id` is unique, `COUNT()` always returns 1.

Remove the `WHERE` clause and add the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT certification_id, 
       COUNT(*) AS cert_count
FROM jobcatlist 
GROUP BY certification_id
HAVING cert_count > 1 AND SUM(jobcategory_id = 1) > 0 
-- or HAVING cert_count > 1 AND MAX(jobcategory_id = 1) = 1
ORDER BY certification_id DESC;
```